# Creating USB connector cable using female-female adapter

Tags: usb-connection-mode, usb-on-the-go, usb-host-mode, htc-one

In order to connect a pen drive to One M8, I tried using a female-female USB adapter with one end connected to my phone via the provided USB cable and a pen drive inserted into the other end.. however this didn't work*.

Can anyone pls provide me the reason for this? Thanks in advance. :)

- after referring to Google I came to know that OTG cable is required.. but why is my setup not working like an OTG cable?

Comment: Also, this setup doesn't work for Galaxy Tab 2 too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In USB, one device acts as the *host*, and others as *peripherals*. USB-on-the-go sockets and cables use particular pins wired together to let each device know which rôle it should play. Your home-made cable didn't have this, so the phone was trying to act as a peripheral, not a host. If you'd learned about USB-OTG before trying to make your own cable, and shorted together the correct pins on the host end of the cable, it would have worked fine.